# Size problems when plotting xy/(x^2+2y^2)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to plot the funtion xy/(x^2+2y^2) using PGFPlots. Here is what I want:

[image: What I want]

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=red,fill=white,very thick,only marks,mark=*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=(\x*\y)/(\x*\x+2*\y*\y);}]
        \begin{axis} [
                axis on top,
                axis equal image,
                axis lines=center,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                zlabel=$z$,
                zmin=-1,
                zmax=1,
                ztick={-1,0,0.33,1},
                zticklabels={$-1$,$0$,$1/3$,$1$},
                ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
                legend pos=outer north east,
                legend style={cells={align=left}},
                legend cell align={left},
                view={-135}{25},
            ]
            \addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=interp,domain=-1:1,domain y=-1:1,samples=61, samples y=61] {f(x,y)};;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: What I have done]

The MWE output has an incredible big zoom, so **I would like to resize the plot but not using `scale` but another commands, like `enlarge limits`.** However, all the results are in vain; I can not reproduce the visual appearance of what I want.

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure you want to plot the function in this way? If you use polar coordinates in the x-y plane, `x=r cos(\phi)` and `y=r sin(\phi)`, you see that the function does not depend on `r` but only on the angle. This explains the behavior at 0, where the function is not well-defined. And otherwise the function depends only on one variable, so I am wondering if you would be better off if you plotted a function of one variable only, or at least use a different parametrization.

Comment: @marmot please see the edit. The function has a "normal" behaviour when changing `domain y=-1.2:1` to `domain y=-1:1`. If you want to use change of variables go ahead :). Do you know how to "enlarge" the axis without rescaling the entire function in order to make it a little more bigger?

Comment: Normally you can set `width=15cm` or something like this. Of course, with `axis equal image,` one needs to be a bit careful. What I meant to say is that the function is not well-defined at `x=y=0` and otherwise only a function that depends on one variable, not on two. You see this actually rather well in the upper plot.

Comment: @marmot yup, with `width=10cm` it is much better. 1. If I want to add `\addlegendentry{Something}` then the box is well above the graphic, rather than accompany it. Do you know how to align it with the graph? 2. Could you post an answer deleting the negative `z` axis, please?

Comment: Forget the second requirement.

Comment: I need to sleep so I will just post some 1d plot.

Comment: I am sorry, I was wrong to think that this was a problem. I am going to change the question. You can delete all positive/negative votes.

Comment: Please do not alter the question that essentially by editing. It is much better to ask a new question.

Comment: @TeXnician thanks. I cannot delete the question, and it is with reason. What sanction do I deserve?

Comment: There is no sanction, but you could rollback the question to a previous state so that the answer actually bases on the question. And then simply ask your new question as new question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not an answer to the (LaTeX part of the) question. However, if you use polar coordinates in the *x*-*y* plane, *x* = *r* cos(*ϕ*) and *y* = *r* sin(*ϕ*), you see that the function does not depend on *r* but only on the angle. So away from the origin *x* = *y* = 0 all the information is already in a one-dimensional plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={fan(\t)=-(sin(2*\t)/(-3 + cos(2*\t)));}]
\begin{axis}
 \addplot[domain=0:360,smooth,samples=101] {fan(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And this yields a 3d smooth plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=red,fill=white,very thick,only marks,mark=*}}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=(\x*\y)/(\x*\x+2*\y*\y);
  fan(\t)=-(sin(2*\t)/(-3 + cos(2*\t)));}]
  \begin{axis} [width=18cm,
          axis on top,
          axis equal image,
          axis lines=center,
          xlabel=$x$,
          ylabel=$y$,
          zlabel=$z$,
          zmin=-1,
          zmax=1,
          ztick={-1,0,0.33,1},
          zticklabels={$-1$,$0$,$1/3$,$1$},
          ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
          legend pos=outer north east,
          legend style={cells={align=left}},
          legend cell align={left},
          view={-135}{25},
          data cs=polar,
      ]

      \addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=interp,domain=0:360,
      domain y=0:1,samples=61, samples y=21,
      z buffer=sort] { fan(x)};
      \addlegendentry{{$f(x,y)$}}
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I edited your answer a bit (you can go to the revisions to see what I changed). If it is not good, be free to roll back to the previous version!